# How to split a string in bash delimited by /

Tags: bash

I have to split a string in a bash script by "/" but I tried:

```
for i in $(echo $www | tr "/")
```

But it did not work, any suggestion ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$ IFS=/ read -a foo <<< 'abc def/ghi/jkl'
$ echo "${foo[0]}*${foo[1]}*${foo[2]}"
abc def*ghi*jkl
```

Comment: Setting IFS is the best way to go. Of course I suspect `$www` won't have spaces but rather `%20`s. Don't forget `unset IFS` at the end! Will also work with `IFS=/ for i in $www; do ... ; done ; unset IFS`

Comment: You don't need to unset `$IFS` at the end since this notation will only set it for the duration of the command.

Answer (score 4):

Your trick would work, if you would tell `tr`, what slash should be translated into:

```
for w in $(echo "what/the/heck" | tr "/" " ") ; do echo $w; done 
what
the
heck
```