# How can I split a string based on a delimiter in bash?

Tags: arrays, linux, string, bash, split

I've defined an array in a .sh file like so:

```
hosts=(NODE IPS)
hosts[0]="1.110,Node-01"
hosts[1]="1.111,Node-02"
hosts[2]="1.112,Node-03"
hosts[3]="1.113,Node-04"
hosts[4]="1.114,Node-05"
hosts[5]="1.115,Node-06"
```

How can I loop over the array, but split each index based on the commma, and store the value in a variable, something like this:

```
for index in ${!hosts[*]}
do
    ip = ## some way to split the string, and get the left side of the index
    hostname = ## some way to split the string, and get the right side of the index
    ## do something with the above variables
    echo "IP: $ip HOSTNAME: $hostname"
done
```

I'm using linux if this helps

Comment: try this `-->` Already answered in a post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479814/how-to-split-a-string-in-bash-delimited-by

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
    IFS=, read ip hostname <<< "$host"
    echo "IP: $ip, HOSTNAME: $hostname"
done
```

Comment: I accepted this answer because it seems very simple!

Answer (score 1):

try this `-->`

1. Using the `tr` to break the string up

   ```
   for w in $(echo "hello/Hi/Bye" | tr "/" " ") ; do echo $w; done
   ```

   OUTPUT

   ```
   Hello
   Hi
   Bye
   ```

2
.  Can use `awk` Statement. Example `--->`
Using “:” as a delimiter for below example

```
$ echo "abc:def" | awk -F':' '{print "field1: "$1 "\nfield2: "$2}'
```

OUTPUT

```
field1: abc
field2: def
```

Comment: Using `for` to parse arbitrary strings is generally not a good idea, because the result is subject to pathname expansion: see what happens when you run `for w in $(echo "hello/Hi/*" | tr "/" " ") ; do echo $w; done`.